# Simple check for value in list not giving expected result

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I'm hosting a script on Pythonanywhere and I have a list of companies and I'm doing a check to see if a company is present in this list. The list of companies is made up of two lists, the first being owner companies and the second being resellers.

```
([<Company 10>, <Company 11>, <Company 12>, <Company 13>, <Company 16>, <Company 14>, <Company 17>, <Company 18>, <Company 19>, <Company 20>, <Company 22>], [<Company 15>, <Company 5>, <Company 6>])
```

Below is a simple check I am carrying out to see if a value is in the first company list.

```
if owner in company_lists[0]:
    print('Owner in list')
else:
    print('Owner not in list')
```

I am printing out the value of owner company for each check and below is an example output

```
Owner is <Company 10>
Owner not in list
```

Am I missing something? As far as I can see both values are present in the list but I am not getting the expected output?

Comment: It's `if owner in company_list:`

Comment: Sorry I should have explained better I have edited my post. The company list is two lists and I want to check if the company is in the first list.

Comment: Can you try this,`if owner.id in [i.id for i in company_lists[0]]:`? What is the Company object here?

Comment: Please add a [mre]. `companies = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]; 'A' in companies[0]` simply works, so there's an error in the code that you didn't show.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'if' is checking only the first element of the list, so it will only find the first company.

Turn

```
if owner in company_lists[0]:
```

into

```
if owner in company_lists:
```